# Replacement of shocks

Tags: shock-absorber

I returned from Namibia late July and took my Pajero (18 months old, 36 000kms) to the dealer to check the shocks. The guarantee is still in force and Mitsubishi decided to replace the front and rear shocks on the right, not the left ones, which are at 55% and 60% of peak performance. Surely replacing shocks on one side of the vehicle and leaving the ones on the other side operating at at marginal levels presents a safety risk? Can somebody provide some expert opinion please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should you replace shocks in pairs?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1464/should-you-replace-shocks-in-pairs)

Comment: Changing one side and not the other leaves the car unbalanced on uneven roads, and stabilizing after a bump, rock or ditch. The unbalance can put more strain on the older shock causing it to wear out faster

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of anyone replacing just one side. I would definitely think that it is a safety risk to have unbalanced shock absorbers.